# Mongo DB How to find common in two arrays and sort in descending order in a single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is my data saves in database

```
0  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4
   name:'John singh',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'5'},
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'8'}
   ],

1  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6g57f5rt
   name:'Josh kumar',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'9'},
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'3'}
   ],

2  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6r67222
   name:'Jesse nigam',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'6'},
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'9'},
       {car_id:'3'}
   ],

3  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6467ii46
   name:'Jordan khan',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'3'},
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'4'},
       {car_id:'5'}
   ]
```

Now I want to search a user with its starting name that is 'J' and also cars_owned by me the input will be

```
  'J',cars_owned['3','7','9','12','10']
```

and the output will be

```
   1  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6g57f5rt
   name:'Josh kumar',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'9'},
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'3'}
   ],

   2  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6r67222
   name:'Jesse nigam',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'6'},
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'9'},
       {car_id:'3'}
   ],

   0  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4
   name:'John singh',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'5'},
       {car_id:'7'},
       {car_id:'8'}
   ],

   3  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb6467ii46
   name:'Jordan khan',
   cars_owned:[
       {car_id:'3'},
       {car_id:'1'},
       {car_id:'4'},
       {car_id:'5'}
   ]
```

and now you will notice the result are all the users whose name starts with 'J' and cars_owned is **in 3,7,9,12,10** but in descending order that is the user with most cars_owned matched in on top and according others. I want the result to be sorted according to maximum cars_owned matched ***in a single mongo db query***. So far I have made one simple find query.

```
  User_data.find({name: { $regex: "^" + search_name },
                  cars_owned:{$elemMatch:{car_id:'3',car_id:'7',car_id:'9',car_id:'12',car_id:'10'} 
                 }},function(err,resp){

                      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp,null,4));

          });
```

but it only returns one document I want all documents which have any of the give car_id but sort by maximum matched. If your don't understand anything in this question feel free to ask in comment but please give answer in a single mongo db query I am also ok with aggeregation framework.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use aggregagtion for this.
First you define how many user's cars are common with your list, then filter results matching name and at least one car common, and finally sort your result by common cars.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      commonCars: {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: [
            [
              "3",
              "7",
              "9",
              "12",
              "10"
            ],
            "$cars_owned.car_id"
          ]
        },

      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$name",
                  regex: "^J"
                }
              },
              true
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              "$commonCars",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "commonCars": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[And you can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QW8sikgKn2q)

---

EDIT

if you don't need to sort your result, you can achieve this in one single match stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$name",
                  regex: "^J"
                }
              },
              true
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $setIntersection: [
                    [
                      "3",
                      "7",
                      "9",
                      "12",
                      "10"
                    ],
                    "$cars_owned.car_id"
                  ]
                },

              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

])
```

[Test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lxsNiwWwC6l)

Comment: That is the answer but I want to search both name and common cars simultaneously. Here in your answer first all the document are scanned for common cars and then in them we are getting names. I also dont want to search name and then find common cars I want to do them both simultaneously (altogether).

Comment: You can perform the $setIntersection operation in a match stage, but in this case you will not be able to perform the $sort operation, as the size of setIntersection result will be computed only for $match stage. And to perform sort, you have to add... this $addFields stage.

Comment: can you give me a query for that I want to get this answer.

Comment: i added it to my previous answer

Comment: My problem was solved I have accepted the answer thanks.